# I am trying to wirte a .py file into the write_eeprom.sh. I am getting the error 'Not Found'

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-20.04

Trying to run this code (using `sh write_eeprom.sh` )

```sh
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                

testdesc=$1
qr_heisys=$2

if [[ $testdesc == "-h" ]]
then
        echo "script to write data to Board EEPROM of Heisys"
        echo "eeprom is at address 0x55"
        echo "first argument is testdesc"
        echo "second argument is qr"
        echo "usage: write_eeprom.sh "write to eeprom" "$qr_heisys""
        exit 0
fi

teststep "${testdesc}"
echo "qr_heisys = "$qr_heisys
${testpath}${script}qr2eeprom.py "$qr_heisys"

if [[ $? -ne "0" ]]
then
        fail "Error writing QR Code to eeprom"
else
        printlog  "Write QR to Boardeeprom was succesfull PASS"
fi
```

Getting the following Errors:

```
write_eeprom.sh: 6: [[: not found

write_eeprom.sh: 16: teststep: not found
qr_heisys = 

write_eeprom.sh: 20: qr2eeprom.py: not found

write_eeprom.sh: 22: [[: not found

write_eeprom.sh: 26: printlog: not found
```

Comment: Sure you're using bash? I bet you aren't.

Comment: So I am using 'sh write_eeprom.sh' to run the code. If okay, can you tell me how are so sure that this isn't bash?

Comment: sh is not bash, it's sh, and doesn't have many features that bash does.

Comment: Ohh okay! Do I need to change the #!/bin/bash to " #!/bin/sh " ? How could I or ways to solve these error ? I used export PATH to give the path, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the script to be executed by `bash` as the shebang line dictates then do

```
chmod +x write_eeprom.sh
./write_eeprom.sh
```

Recommendation: you don't need the `.sh` extension, you can rename it as just `write_eeprom` and use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your script

Comment: Thank You!! This worked! Also the shellcheck.net was useful!